# Machine learning book with code examples

Tags: machine-learning, references

I am studying Machine Learning and implementing ML algorithms with Matlab. I follow Ethem Alpaydin, Duda and Hart, Bishop and Mitchell's books. However none of them exactly give the pseudo codes and algorithm based examples and code snippets as usual.

Are there any books which follow topics with code examples with Matlab or Java or Python?

Answer (score 4):

[Machine Learning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420067184), Stephen Marsland.
One of the best practical, Python based, texts I've come across.

Comment: agree with that easy to read not as confusing as Bishop for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

[Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Brml.HomePage) by Barber. It is freely available. In addition, there is [Matlab toolbox](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Brml.Software) of the book.

Comment: Seems good, though I'd like to avoid matlab. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The recently published

> [Machine learning: a probabilistic perspective, By Kevin Murphy](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/)

comes with an excellent and [very extensive Matlab](http://code.google.com/p/pmtk3/) toolkit for Machine learning, which includes code for examples discussed in the book.

Comment: I'd prefer to not use proprietary software, but the book seems to be very valuable from a theoretical standpoint, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WEKA is fully implemented in Java.

http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/

It has its own manual and [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123748569). You can find the manual in the WEKA directory if you install it or straight away in the zip file if you don't download the self-extracting.